# Using watch or alternative to watch multiple commands at once

Tags: watch

While running data-heavy scripts that take a long time to run, I like to use these commands to monitor the status/progress of the script. I can then leave the constantly-updating output open as sort of a progress bar.

```
watch qstat #see status of job in our SGE_Batch query system
watch ls -lhrt #show organized information for all files in working directory
```

I sometimes switch between these, for example, when the output files stop growing in size but I want to make sure my script is still running.

To avoid having to switch or use multiple terminal windows, how can I use watch or a similar function to get a constantly-updating output of results from two functions (qstat and ls) at once?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

make a command-line that runs both and combines the output.

```
watch 'qstat | head ; ls -lhrt'
```

or better, run each watch in a different pane of a tmux session.